# Template function to return template type

Tags: c++, templates, return-value

I have the following function but my compiler (VS2003) says that the assignement T = .... is illegal.  Can someone clarify what I've done wrong?  The type of value is a boost::variant.  node is a struct.

```
 template <typename T>
    T find_attribute(const std::string& attribute)
    {

        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<node> >::iterator nodes_iter = _request->begin();

        for (; nodes_iter != _request->end(); nodes_iter++)
        {
            std::vector<node::attrib>::iterator att_iter = (*nodes_iter)->attributes.begin();
            for (; att_iter != att_iter; (*nodes_iter)->attributes.end())
            {
                if ((*att_iter).key.compare(attribute) == 0) {
                    T = (*att_iter).value;  //T : Illegal use of this type as an expression.
                                    return T; 
                            }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare a variable:

```
if ((*att_iter).key.compare(attribute) == 0) {
    T temp = (*att_iter).value;  //T : Illegal use of this type as an expression.
    return temp; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`T` is a *type*, not a variable name. In the general case, you should declare a variable as mentioned by @sharptooth (this is the usual workflow for any function!).

In your particular case, it’s better just to return the value – no additional variable is needed:

```
return (*att_iter).value;
```

or, better yet:

```
return att_iter->value;
```